# How to link standard library to a cross-compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, xv6

I want to build xv6 on macOS, so I installed the cross-compiler toolchain i386-elf-gcc and i386-elf-gcc from a [Homebrew Tap](https://github.com/nativeos/homebrew-i386-elf-toolchain).

The problem is i386-elf-gcc cant link standard libraries while compiling. I tested on a simple c file, and got the following error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("d\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
> i386-elf-gcc --sysroot=usr/includes test.c
test.c:1:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: looks like a bad installation. (cross)Compilers are coming with the standard libraries and headers

Comment: "problem is i386-elf-gcc cant link standard libraries" --> not quite.  So far it is not a _linking_ problem, but the compiler is confused where the standard headers reside.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Do you think it might be caused by this [option](https://github.com/nativeos/homebrew-i386-elf-toolchain/blob/ec10b3a3848b8bc210ce25e5fd6d66057003a8a8/Formula/i386-elf-gcc.rb#L20) in the homebrew tap?

Comment: @chux I added a `--sysroot=usr/includes` option to this gcc, but it doesn't really help.

Comment: Have you actually used that option?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is on the Homebrew tap, so I guess homebrew uses this configuration to build i386-elf-gcc.

Comment: Well. No. This option is telling not to use any of the target headers when *building* gcc. Can you locate the headers in the toolchain path?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I found `/usr/local/Cellar/i386-elf-gcc/7.3.0/lib/gcc/i386-elf/7.3.0/include`, but I am not sure it is the right path? Interestingly there are `stdint.h`, `float.h`, but no `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve, you could try adding the newlib library and cross-compile it to your architecture. The following link says the freeware newlib can be used as source of the stdlib to compile all by yourself.

[One problem is that the standard libraries provided with most software development tool suites arrive only in object form...](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-embedded-systems/0596009836/ch04.html#ID-d1766e1174:%7E:text=a%20freeware%20version%20of%20the%20standard%20C%20library%20for%20use%20in%20embedded%20systems)